If $(f\in F_1)\Rightarrow[(f\in F_2)\Leftrightarrow(f\in F_3)]$ and $(f\in F_1)\Rightarrow[(f\in F_2)\Leftrightarrow(f\in F_4)] $, then $F_3=F_4$?
I am trying to write a proof, but I’m not sure whether my last step is legitimate. Let me expose a simplified version of my problem.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be arbitrary finite sets, let $f:X\to Y$ be some function, let $F=Y^X$ be the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$, and let $F_1,F_2,F_3,F_4\subsetneq F$ be sets of functions from $X$ to $Y$.
Now, consider these two statements:
\begin{equation}
(f\in F_1)\Rightarrow[(f\in F_2)\Leftrightarrow(f\in F_3)]\\
(f\in F_1)\Rightarrow[(f\in F_2)\Leftrightarrow(f\in F_4)]
\end{equation}
In my proof, I write that given the above statements, it follows that $F_3=F_4$. While a part of me feels that this is true, another part of me feels there is something fishy with my claim and that I should instead write
\begin{gather}
(f\in F_1)\Rightarrow[(f\in F_3)\Leftrightarrow(f\in F_4)]
\end{gather}
So,
QUESTION: Is it true that $F_3=F_4$ given the aforementioned two statements?

The two given statements are together logically equivalent to \begin{equation}
f\in F_1\Rightarrow\Big((f\in F_2\Leftrightarrow f\in F_3) \land (f\in F_2\Leftrightarrow f\in F_4)\Big),\tag1
\end{equation}
which logically implies that
$$f\in F_1\Rightarrow(f\in F_3\Leftrightarrow f\in F_4),$$
which means that both $\boldsymbol{(F_1\cap F_3)\setminus F_4}$ and $\boldsymbol{(F_1\cap F_4)\setminus F_3}$ contain no function.
It isn't necessary that $F_3=F_4,$ since, for example, a function $f$ lying in $(F_3\setminus F_4)\setminus F_1$ does satisfy statement $(1).$

Suppose $F_1$ is the the empty set of functions from $X$ to $Y$.
Then your two initial statements are vacuously true, whatever $F_3$ and $F_4$ are, …

Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please complete the sentence “whenever $F_3$ and $F_4$ are…”?

It's "whatever", not "whenever". The ellipsis invites you to complete the argument in the obvious way.

Both statements only apply for functions $f$ that are in $F_1$. They do not, however, provide any info about elements outside $F_1$.
Given the two statements, the best we can conclude is, as per your conclusion:
$$ (f \in F_1) \Rightarrow [(f \in F_3) \Leftrightarrow (f \in F_4)] $$
Therefore it is not true that $F_3$ = $F_4$.

You mean: we can’t infer from the given data that $F_3 = F_4$. But that doesn’t rule out the identity happening to hold…

Thank you very much for your answer.
@PeterSmith
Could you please help me see what additional data on the given sets would be needed to make the identity hold?
